# \spinemargin and \footskip error with memoir

Tags: errors, memoir

I get the following errors when I am using `memoir`.

`! Class memoir Error: \spinemargin (97.26999pt) and/or \textwidth (271.73482pt)`

`! Class memoir Error: \footskip (27.46295pt) is too large for \lowermargin (-34
    .248pt) by 61.71095pt.`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[size=pocket,trim,bleed]{createspace}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
Foo bar
\end{document}
```

How can I go about solving this issue? I am also using [`createspace` (GitHub)](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/wiki/documentation) package, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Backticks will not work in the title. It is better to remove them to make the title more beautiful.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a MWE. See my answer at [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for some tips.

Comment: @doncherry I have reduced it as much as I can now.

Comment: I don't have the `createspace` package installed but if I uncomment it together with `\pdftitle`, `\pdfauthor` and `\pdfsubject` and also `\include{Conclusion}` in order to be able to run the code there is no error. So I think this issue is either due to `createspace` or to something you have in `Conclusion.tex`.

Comment: I reduced your code further to a real MWE. The errors indeed seem to come from `createspace` only (@cgnieder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memoir`'s `\checkandfixthelayout` is problematic in this particular case, but invoking it does not seem necessary, here.

According to the very [link](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/wiki/documentation) to the `createspace` documentation that you provided ,

- the combination of options `size=pocket` and `trim` (equivalent to `trim=1`) set the paperwidth at 5.06in and paperweight at 7.81in, and
- the `bleed` option extends the page size by 0.125 on top, bottom and outer margins, which means an additional 0.125in in width and an additional 0.25in in height.

Total paperwidth: 5.06in + 0.125in = 5.185in

Total paperwidth: 7.81in + 0.25in = 8.06in

The Inspector tool in Mac OS Preview indicates that the output document produced by the code below has the desired paper size (the figures given are rounded to the nearest 0.01 inch).

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[size=pocket,trim,bleed]{createspace}
\pdftitle{Me, myself, and I}
\pdfauthor{Narcisse}
\begin{document}
Foo bar
\end{document}
```