# Chapter page numbers outside of margins memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, chapters

When I send the file to createspace for their online reviewer, it tells me that a few page numbers are outside the margins, which happen to be the ones for each chapter when each chapter begins. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[size=pocket,trim,bleed]{createspace}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
foo bar
\end{document}
```

I am using [`createspace` (GitHub)](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/wiki/documentation) package for this.

EDIT: Is there a way to just remove the numbers when each chapter begins?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the english words gutter and bleed. I suggest you ask better in the chat.

Comment: You don't need geometry. Memoir has a complete set of commands for you to specify every detail of the sheet, page, textblock and margin dimensions. If you know what these should be, we can help you to configure your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote in a comment that you used the `createspace` package only because you didn't get the desired results with the `geometry` package.

Based on the problems with `createspace` that you reported elsewhere ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107284/spinemargin-and-footskip-error-with-memoir/107428#107428) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/createspace-template-for-a-pocket-book)), my advice is to eschew that package unless you absolutely have to use it; stick to more established packages like `geometry` as much as possible.
**The problem you're having with chapter numbers ending up outside the text area should then disappear.**

The following code, which uses the `geometry` package and *not* the `createspace` package, should give you what you want; see [my answer to your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107428/21891) for a detailed calculation of the paper geometry.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\geometry{
    paperheight=8.06in,
    %top=.5in,
    %bottom=.5in, 
    paperwidth=5.185in,
    %inner=.5in,
    %outer=.5in,
    bindingoffset=.3in,
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapter{My second chapter}
\end{document}
```

You still have to set the margins to your taste but note that, with the `geometry` package,

1. The vertical page geometry is set by three independent lengths out of four possible lengths:
   `paperheight` = `top` + `textheight` + `bottom`;
2. The horizontal page geometry is set by three independent lengths out of four possible lengths:
   `paperwidth` = `inner` + `textwidth` + `outer`.
3. The `bindingoffset` option increases the inner margin by the specified length, at the expense of `textwidth`; the `gutter` option seems to be `createspace`'s equivalent to `geometry`'s `bindingoffset`.

Comment: I updated the file and everything seems to look right. I'm going to upload soon to createspace and see what it's online reviewer thinks. However, now I get a whole host of `underfull \vbox` errors which I did not get before. What could be the issue?

Comment: This type of complaints from LaTeX depend on the contents of your input file. Difficult to tell without seeing it. That said, I wouldn't worry too much about underfull and overfull warnings, especially if the output document looks right to you. Feel free to accept my answer(s) if you're happy with them :)

Comment: Okay fantastic! I uploaded the file and it said that the file was smaller than 5.25" x 8" and it was actually 5.18" x 8". Should I change the `paperheight` and `paperwidth` accordingly?

Comment: Yes. You can also change the values of the margins (`inner`, `outer`, `top`, `bottom`) to your taste.

Comment: It seems that when I change the `paperheight` and the `paperwidth` to 5.25" x 8" respectively, the issue with chapter numbers is back. I increased the `bottom` but now everything is shifted. When I increase one thing, do I have to increase them all?

Comment: `geometry` does what it's supposed to. I assume that you submit your pdf so that it be checked online. You must not have complied with their margin requirements. Make sure you adhere to the latter.