# Createspace template for a pocket book

Tags: margins, geometry

I have been used [`createspace` (GitHub)](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/wiki/documentation) package but that is not giving me the desired results. I have attempted to use the `geometry` package with the following code:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.325in, paperheight=8.125in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
```

But I don't think this is inline with [createspace guidelines](https://www.createspace.com/Products/Book/InteriorPDF.jsp). Therefore, my question is, I have done this correctly? And if not, how can I fix it?

EDIT:

The createspace guidelines require that the inside margin of the document is .75 and the outside margin is 0.5. I am using the trim size `5.25 x 8`.

**UPDATE:**

I uploaded the file with the code the that @Jubobs provided and I still get the following message:

> Insufficient gutter, books from 151 - 400 pages require at least .75" for the gutter (inside margin) and at least .25" for the outside, top and bottom margins.

When I used the in-built function, the words were not too much out of the margins but now they are out of the margins by a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `createspace` package seems to clash with some options of the `geometry` package. However, the [very `createspace` documentation you link to](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/wiki/documentation) shows how to customize the geometry of the document by passing options to the `createspace` package.

Do you not get the desired result with the code below? The Inspector tool in Mac OS Preview indicates that the output document has the desired width and height (the figures given are rounded to the nearest 0.01 inch).

Or did you simply overlook that feature in the `createspace` documentation?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[customsize={5.325in,8.125in},gutter=.75in]{createspace}
\pdftitle{Me, myself, and I}
\pdfauthor{Narcisse}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the in-built function which indicated that everything was set but apparently not (I should have read the documentation more carefully). I am going to updated my file with the code that you have provided and then upload to createspace and see if it complains - it should not. I will update shortly.